# Ember-Data destroyRecord stays in local store

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am on ember 1.8.1 and ember-data beta 12

If I do a createRecord and the user chooses not to save it, on the route deactivation I am trying to do model.destroyRecord() however, it continues to be available in my local store with a currentState.stateName: root.deleted.saved

I can't seem to remove it from my local store and I don't know why. Why does the record have a stateName of `root.deleted.saved` and still available when I do a `store.find`?

Edit:
I don't know if it matters, but after cancel and I destroy the record (or attempt to), I end up in a location where am using an each with an itemController. My weirdness, I think, began with the introduction of that.

```
// new/route.js  (using ember-cli pods)
deactivate: function() {
    this._super();
    // if we navigated away without saving the model we should remove it
    //  so we don't have 'unsaved' items displayed anywhere
    var model = this.controller.get('model');
    if(model.get('isDirty')) {
        model.deleteRecord(); // Updated based on MrVinz suggestion below
    }
}
```

The template we transition into

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      ...
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {{#each item in filteredItems itemController="cons"}} 
      ... (my unsaved items are showing up in here, and they should have been deleted) ...
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the workflow and problem you're experiencing? Are you positive your call to your server isn't returning the record again?

Comment: could you please show us a minimal / resumed implementation of the model / setupController you are making your transitionTo, and may be show us how you declare/get your filteredItems :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you didn't did a model.save() of your record before i think that `model.destroyRecord()` is not the best method to call. I would preferably go for a model.rollback() or a model.deleteRecord().

I bellive so because `createRecord` do not trigger any server/api call from your store  <del>but with `destroyRecord()` you actually may perform an unwanted server side server/api call (i didn't check the code of `destroyRecord()` but the doc state it does a model.save() in the process :)</del>

**After discussions in the comments i investigated further :**

You wont, unless implementation changed in beta12, trigger an API call with destroyRecord() on an unsaved object.

**however**

you will then deal with a promise and have a chain of called functions which both have a cost (in therm of resources).

Comment: `destroyRecord` calls `deleteRecord` then `save`.  Maybe that's what you're saying here, if so, feel free to ignore my comment.

Comment: @Kingping2k it's exactly what i am saying

Comment: @Kingpin2k or the guys who vote me down please justify as i think my answer is not that bad. In fact : the model.destroyRecord will call a model.save(), If ember handels properly the things the backend will not be called, if not the backend may rize an error. Even if ember manages properly the save call done by model.destroyRecord the operation still has a cost and is useless in this situation.

Comment: `destroyRecord` won't call back to the server if the record is `root.deleted.save`, which is the state `deleteRecord` places a new record in.  `deleteRecord` or `rollback` of a new record will place it in that state.  I'll gladly reverse my vote if you'll fix up your answer to reflect that, unfortunately all three of those methods should result in the same result, which means his code should be the same with each.  So his problem should still be occurring whether using `deleteRecord`/`destroyReord`/`rollback`

Comment: @Kingpin2k edited, however the 3 methods are note equivalent as you still deal with a promise if you do a destroyRecord() which is note the case with the two other.

Comment: We're probably arguing different things, but in this case all 3 of them do result in the same thing.  Just because one of them returns a promise doesn't mean you have to deal with the promise.  It does as you say cost slightly more.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately my issue stemmed from inadvertently messing with the `isDeleted` property ember-data provides. I had the following:

```
isDrafted: Ember.computed.equal('status', 'Drafted'),
isSubmitted: Ember.computed.equal('status', 'Submitted'),
isValidated: Ember.computed.equal('status', 'Validated'),
isRecalled: Ember.computed.equal('status', 'Recalled'),
isReturned: Ember.computed.equal('status', 'Returned'),
```

One of my status's is 'Deleted' and so I defined an `isDeleted` that was causing all my issues. Lesson learned, maybe I should make my computed properties more explicit like `isStatusDeleted`, `isStatusDrafted`, etc